# How to add dependency in SBT 0.7.x

Tags: scala, sbt

Just getting started with SBT (0.7.7) and I'm reading the docs on automatic dependency management here: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Library-Management.

It says I can do something like:

```
libraryDependencies += "group" % "artifact" % "version"
```

but when I tried that it complains that I'm modifying a val. I'm seeing some stuff about migrating from 0.7.x => 0.10.x and I'm wondering if the docs are for 0.10 and not 0.7.

Comment: That's for sbt 0.10.0, not for sbt 0.7.7.

Comment: Is there documentation for 0.7.7, or are the wiki docs always updated to be for the current version?

Comment: The documentation for SBT up to 0.7.7 is [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Setup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I usually add dependencies in 0.7.x is simply by declaring another val in the project definition class, which SBT will pick up and use

```
val fooDependency = "foo" % "bar" % "version"
```

after adding the lines, just run the "reload" and "update" commands, and SBT will automatically download the dependencies and put them in your lib_managed folder.

I haven't used 0.10 yet so I don't know if this is valid for that.

Comment: this is true, I guess I'm just wondering what version the docs are written for...